# dynamic List<T>.Add throwing RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I'm working on writing some extension methods to the OrientDB .Net library, mapping between model classes in C# and graphs in the database (and vice-versa). This necessarily requires a bit of reflection and dynamic programming.

The following method is used to set the value of properties on a model object which represent the edges between vertices. For example, if vertex A is linked to several vertices B with edges C, the model A may have a property of type `List<B>` while the model B would have a property of type `A` (for a one-to-many relationship).

```csharp
private static void SetLinkedProperty(
    ABaseModel parent, ABaseModel child, string className)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = parent.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                       BindingFlags.Instance |
                       BindingFlags.SetProperty |
                       BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    PropertyInfo propertySingle = properties
        .Where(prop => IsModelProperty(prop, className)).SingleOrDefault();
    PropertyInfo propertyCollection = properties
        .Where(prop => IsModelCollectionProperty(prop, className)).SingleOrDefault();
    if (propertySingle != null)
    {
        propertySingle.SetValue(parent, child);
    }
    if (propertyCollection != null)
    {
        dynamic propertyValue = propertyCollection.GetValue(parent);
        if (propertyValue == null)
        {
            Type listOfT = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(
                propertyCollection.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
            IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(listOfT);
            propertyValue = collection;
            propertyCollection.SetValue(parent, collection);
        }

        propertyValue.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Properties in a model can have attributes giving them an alias to help mapping between the DB and the C# class, so `IsModelProperty` and `IsModelCollectionProperty` checks against that alias as well as whether the property type is an enumerable type.

When I run my code, however, I'm getting a `RuntimeBinderException` at the line `propertyValue.Add(child)`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in OrientTest.exe
>
> Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(OrientTest.Participant)' has some invalid arguments

At the point of the exception:

- `parent` is an instance of `OrientTest.Employer`
- `child` is an instance of `OrientTest.Participant`
- `className` is "EmployerParticipant" (the name of the edge class linking Employer and Participant vertices together in the DB)
- `properties` contains 7 elements, each corresponding to one property in `Employer`
- `propertySingle` is `null`
- `propertyCollection` represents the property `List<Participant> Participants`
- `propertyValue` is an instance of `List<Participant>`

I don't understand why `List<Participant>#Add(Participant)` has invalid arguments, but `dynamic` often does strange things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overload resolution fails because the type of `child` is `ABaseModel`, not `OrientTest.Participant`. It doesn't matter that its value at runtime happens to be of the type the method expects. This seems counter-intuitive given the name `RuntimeBinder`, but there's sense in it: the rules for overload resolution, though applied at runtime, are the same as those C# uses at compile time (because the `dynamic` is really a plain old C# object). Deviating from this would lead to even more surprises.

You can, of course, override or circumvent this behavior if you write your own `DynamicObject` implementation, so this is not a general restriction of `dynamic` -- it just means you cannot (ab)use `dynamic` to do method resolution at runtime this way.

In this case, there's a simple fix if you know the property is always of type `List<T>` for some `T`, because `List<T>` implements `IList` which accepts any old `object` (with a possible runtime exception):

```
IList propertyValue = (IList) propertyCollection.GetValue(parent);
...
propertyValue.Add(child);
```

If you don't know it's a list, you'll have to bite the bullet and invoke the `Add` method dynamically:

```
object propertyValue = propertyCollection.GetValue(parent);
...
propertyValue.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(propertyValue, child);
```

This in turn fails if the object has multiple `.Add()` methods of which you want to use the "most correct" one. I'm assuming we don't need to cover that particular case.

There is actually a third approach, which is overkill here but could be useful in other circumstances, and that is to make the argument itself `dynamic` so resolution is forced to do "the right thing" at runtime (for some values of "right"):

```
propertyValue.Add((dynamic) child);
```